# PWA Setup in Magento 2.3.1 on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: magento2.3, pwa, pwa-studio

I've everything setup ready according to https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

[image]

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Anyone tried for solution ?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, as I noticed all the solutions found they are for Linux machines  only.